# MCMC chain stuck in adaptive phase?

Tags: r, logistic, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, bugs

I'm using R,OpenBUGS and R2OpenBUGS package on Linux Mint and i'm fitting a bayesian multinomial logistic model. After dribbling a lot of usual errors on my way to get my model running, i came upon an error i can't get the grasp of how to solve it.

So after "model is syntactically correct,data loaded, model compiled,initial values generated, model initialized" messages,
 i get 
"inference can not be made when sampler is in adaptive phase".

Does anyone know what exactly this message mean and how could i solve it?
Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you've figured this out by now, but just in case this saves somebody else a bit of time, OpenBUGS and JAGS will not return model results if the number of iterations you run are less than a certain number. I'm guessing because you were debugging your model you were only running a few iterations, but now that you're out of the debug phase you could increase your iterations.